# Create a customizable menu bar in a Python Gui

Tags: python, tkinter, module, menu, menubar

How can I create a menu bar in Python using. I should be able to customize the size of this bar and the colour of this bar. For example, this bar is red and the height of the bar is quite large.
[Example of what I want to be able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAN8d.jpg)

I have found multiple different videos and articles on how to create a menu bar using TKinter. However, all of these videos/ articles create a menu bar without changing the colour or size of the bar. I have also looked at other Python modules and have fund no modules that are easy to use and can create good GUI's. Could I do this using TKinter or will I need to use a different module. Give me a few different examples of other modules that I can use to complete this task?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `Menu` widget to achieve that result. You will have to create a frame, and put whatever widgets you want in that frame. You can then put that frame along the top of the window.